# How to avoid that a tabItem loses colour

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, tabitem

I have a `WPF` program with a `tabItems` interfaces set on the left hand side.

What I want is that the `tabItem` keeps the `colour` as in the following picture:

[image]

Please notice where is the mouse pointer. When there the `tabItem` is `coloured`.

When going in another part of the interface on the right the `tabItem` **looses the colour and gets embossed**:

[image]

I am not sure if it helps posting my `xaml` file helps.
Basically I noticed that when the arrow goes on a `datagrid` on the right the `tabItem` is coloured when going on the free space it isn't.

Please notice that  I don't want the `tabItem` to be of a particular colour, it has to follow the system palette and so to be in the correct system colour.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752032(VS.85).aspx) from Microsoft describing how to use `ColorTemplate` with `Triggers` to solve your issue.

Here is the example from article in case in the future the link is down for some reason:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Grid>
          <Border 
            Name="Border"
            Margin="0,0,-4,0" 
            Background="{StaticResource LightBrush}"
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" 
            BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
            CornerRadius="2,12,0,0" >
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              ContentSource="Header"
              Margin="12,2,12,2"
              RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
          </Border>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Resources:**

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
  <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    <GradientStopCollection>
      <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="1.0"/>
    </GradientStopCollection>
  </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>

  ...

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#888" />

  ...

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />

  ...

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="#EEE" />

  ...

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />

  ...

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />
```